# beamer: itemize do not honor text color

Tags: beamer, color, itemize, animations

I understand that each `\item` within an `itemize` does not honor the text color because it is within its own group.

Anyhow, I have a program that generates for me a bunch of boxes, one of which is "active".

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand\MyBoxInactive[1]{
\begin{minipage}[b][.20\textheight][t]{.20\textwidth}\color{gray}#1\end{minipage}
}
\newcommand\MyBoxActive[1]{
\colorbox{yellow}{\begin{minipage}[b][.20\textheight][t]{.20\textwidth}#1\end{minipage}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
\MyBoxInactive{\begin{itemize}\item item1\item item 2\end{itemize}}
\MyBoxInactive{\begin{itemize}\item item1\item item 2\end{itemize}}
\MyBoxActive{\begin{itemize}\item item1\item item 2\end{itemize}}
\MyBoxInactive{\begin{itemize}\item item1\item item 2\end{itemize}}
\MyBoxInactive{\begin{itemize}\item item1\item item 2\end{itemize}}
\MyBoxInactive{\begin{itemize}\item item1\item item 2\end{itemize}}
\MyBoxInactive{\begin{itemize}\item item1\item item 2\end{itemize}}
\MyBoxInactive{\begin{itemize}\item item1\item item 2\end{itemize}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I set the other boxes font to be gray?

(preferably without changing the content, just as going to each \item and setting is gray, because these slides are generated by several processes, and another process is the one that chooses the active box ...)

Comment: Why don't you use `transparent` rather than changing the colour by force? Or create an overlay-sensitive analogue of `uncover` or `alt` or whatever your need similar to the transparency option. You don't need a hack and a hack is going to be much more work than using the facilities Beamer offers, I suspect. At least, *start* with what Beamer can do before you resort to a hack.

Comment: The thing is my use case is a little more complex than what I am exhibiting here. I only used animations for the purpose of the MWE. I have a program that generates frames with four quadrants, one of which is highlighted and the rest is inactive. I am aware of animations and `\setbeamercovered`, and I have used animations for this MWE, but this is for something for which animation is not really feasible ...

Comment: So? It is just a style. You can apply a transparency-like effect (which can be anything) to every slide in the frame, to only some, to whatever. But if you don't want the overlay stuff, it is simpler - you just need to use Beamer's colours with no transitions to worry about. But you need to use Beamer's colour framework for it to work properly - just setting colours the non-Beamer way won't work properly.

Comment: A manual workaround: `\begin{itemize}\only<1>{\color{gray}}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\end{itemize}`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina A broader solution would be more helpful, because the content is produced by several processes.

Comment: @cfr, I am not *that* good with Beamer I am afraid :P Do you mean I could perhaps embed my frame with the same environment used by `overlays`? E.g. something like: `\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{uncoverenv}{1}
Hello World
\end{uncoverenv}
\end{frame}`

Comment: If you don't want overlays, why make it complicated? But you need to use Beamer colours rather than regular colours. You could probably do something analogous to something some of the overlay specifications do. But the overlay stuff is just manipulating Beamer colours as far as I know. (It isn't 'true' transparency, for example.)

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly your suggestion is to somehow tell that part of the slide that it must uncover, so that it gets gray-ed out by Beamer without generating new slides. Is that what your saying? I agree something like that would be cool. Whatever works ...

Comment: @cfr, I have re-worked the MWE to be more faithful to my use case. Please let me know what you had in mind could be applied to it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image: active/inactive]

This is not the 'right' way to do it but it involves minimal disruption to existing code. In particular, the frame content need not be altered.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand\MyBoxInactive[1]{%
  \begin{minipage}[b][.20\textheight][t]{.20\textwidth}%
    \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=gray}\usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}%
    \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=gray}\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}%
    #1
  \end{minipage}}
\newcommand\MyBoxActive[1]{%
  \colorbox{yellow}{%
    \begin{minipage}[b][.20\textheight][t]{.20\textwidth}#1\end{minipage}}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}{Title}
    \MyBoxInactive{\begin{itemize}\item item1\item item 2\end{itemize}}
    \MyBoxInactive{\begin{itemize}\item item1\item item 2\end{itemize}}
    \MyBoxActive{\begin{itemize}\item item1\item item 2\end{itemize}}
    \MyBoxInactive{\begin{itemize}\item item1\item item 2\end{itemize}}
    \MyBoxInactive{\begin{itemize}\item item1\item item 2\end{itemize}}
    \MyBoxInactive{\begin{itemize}\item item1\item item 2\end{itemize}}
    \MyBoxInactive{\begin{itemize}\item item1\item item 2\end{itemize}}
    \MyBoxInactive{\begin{itemize}\item item1\item item 2\end{itemize}}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant! It is exactly what I wanted! :)

Answer (score 0):

How about using TikZ to define your boxes? Something along these lines:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.5em, text margin right=0.5em}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\color{black}\bfseries\insertframetitle\par\vskip-6pt\hrulefill}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0.3},
    visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
  }

\newcommand\FourQuad[4]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[minimum height=.4\textheight,text width=0.45\textwidth,anchor=north west,visible on=<1>,alt=<1>{fill=yellow}{}]
  (col1a)
  at ([shift={(10pt,.4\textheight)}]current page.west) 
  {#1};
\node[minimum height=.4\textheight,text width=0.45\textwidth,right=4pt of col1a,visible on=<2>,alt=<2>{fill=yellow}{}] 
  {#2};
\node[minimum height=.4\textheight,text width=0.45\textwidth,below=10 pt of col1a.south west,anchor=north west,visible on=<3>,alt=<3>{fill=yellow}{}]
  (col1b)
  {#3};
\node[minimum height=.4\textheight,text width=0.45\textwidth,right=4pt of col1b,visible on=<4->,alt=<4>{fill=yellow}{}] 
  {#4};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A frame divided in two sides}
\FourQuad{First contents and some more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text}%
{A few items:
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\end{itemize}
And that's almost it!}%
{A few items:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\end{enumerate}
And that's it!}%
{First contents and some more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The resulting slides:

[image]